# How to order executions in one phase?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have two `<execution>`s attached to the same phase `deploy`. First execution is `tomcat:redeploy`, second one is a custom one that makes a HTTP request to the production server to validate that the application really works.

How can I instruct maven to execute them in this particular order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-2258, try Maven 3.

Comment: I'm using Maven 3. According to MNG-2258 there is no possibility to do this?

Comment: Well, the issue is still open.

Another option would be to use pre-integration-test/integration-test/post-integration-test phases or to write an own plugin.